# Making an Emission shader emit a different colour of light than the colour assigned to the object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am making a skydome and I have a texture hooked up with an emission shader for it, however, since the dome is blue it only emits blue light. Is there a way that I can have the whole sky illuminated and have the light reaching the rest of my scene be a different colour?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you want in one material but have a possible workaround. Have you considered duplicating the dome, adding an emission material (with the color you want), and setting the object settings to only render the emission?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are using Cycles (which you never state what render engine you are using) use a light path node with the *Is Camera* output socket.

This will tell Blender that the visible color of the object is the one specified, but the emission remains whatever you specify in the above node.

[image: Light Path node]

Comment: This works great, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Also I will try to state more important details in the future.