# Is it possible to have a 2d element interacting with a 3d world?

Tags: rendering, shaders

I want to know if it possible to simulate an augmented reality situation in Blender without the elements negatively interact with one another. I already know about using the emission shader on a 2d object to simulate a flat appearance of it, but such a technique would have an impact on the interaction in a 3d enviroment (i.e undesired light would be casting on the environment). What would be a technique to bypass that?

Comment: Use layers and render layers, the elements can remain independent and not interact at all and combine them using the compositor.

Comment: See my answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/58280#58280 You can use the same technique to mix any two shaders. In your case you can have an emission shader for the visible component of the material and say a transparent shader for everything else, making the material virtually neutral to your scene and every other object.