# Why are my emissive faces of a different color than the light they emit?

Tags: materials, light, faces, color

I made a selection of faces on an object emissive. They radiate orange light. However, the faces themselves are still white. How can I make sure they are the same color as the light they emit?

[image: Setup]

Comment: They are the same color, they are simply overexposed. I suspect if you lowered the emission intensity far enough they would eventually become the color you expected. [Here is a possible solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig) to your problem

Comment: Ah you're right! I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!