# Making Textured Surface Emit Light

Tags: texturing, light

In cycles render, I would like to make a textured surface emit light **while the texture is still showing**. Tried various methods (some suggested here) but haven't really found a solution. The ideal resolution would be if I could make the surface emit light but not lighting itself (so the texture remains visible). Is something like that possible?

This is what I have:

[image]

Comment: You can add texture to the emission shader too. Just plug it in the color shocket.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/58280#58280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: final]

You can mix your texture with **Emission** Shader through ***Light Path > Is Camera Ray***.
This way you can have basically two shaders at once.

You can change **Emission Color** and plug base color texture to it.

[image: nodes]

Comment: oh yes of course  ;)

Comment: This has done it; yours is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So what have you tried so far? Have you tried to duplicate your object, give the copy a higher *Emission Strength* and make it invisible to the camera?

- Create a copy of your object and duplicate its material.
- Scale the copy or move it above the original object.
- Go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* and choose *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire* to make it easier to manipulate in *Object* mode.
- Go in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycle Settings* and deactivate the *Camera* option to make your object invisible in *Render* mode.
- Give this copy a higher *Emission Strength* so that it emits more light than the original and can enlight its environment.

[image]

Comment: I consider duplicating the object a messy hack; so, no, I have not considered it. In all honestly, if there is no elegant solution, I'd rather place a light source inside my object and make the emitting surface slightly transparent, or even place an area light right in front of it.

Comment: sure it's not perfect, it's just a quick trick that will give a good result most of the time though. About what you say, for example if you use an area light it won't project the texture all around, I thought you wanted this, so maybe putting a light source inside your object is the best (and most realistic) solution in your case...

Comment: Actually I think Cgslav has given the elegant solution  ;)

Answer (score 0):

> ... algorithms model diffuse inter-reflection which is a very important part of global illumination

You are not understading [blender node system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/introduction.html) and [global illumination principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination).

> An important concept to understand when building node setups is that of the shader socket. The output of all surface and volume shaders is a shader, describing lighting interaction at the surface or of the volume, rather than the color of the surface.

1. Do not use texture as shader: use diffuse or other to simulate the physical properties of the material.
2. You need to iluminate textured surface by other light source, world or volume.

Self illuminated
[image: Self illuminated]

Inderect illuminated by volume and world background for a 0.01 white
[image: Inderect illuminated by volume and world background for a 0.01 white]