# How to render objects with self illumination?

Tags: rendering, lighting, emission

Pretty new to blender, but i feel like i have gotten off to a good start. With that said, i have one issue that i have been struggling over the past week to get a hang off, and that is how to render my character with self illumination.

I am trying to achieve something similar to how they did Ori (detailed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8lOwrWNbEY around the 6:10 mark).

I have an unlighted scene with transparent background. I either end up with something that is fully illuminated (white silhouette) or when trying a few other solutions (like this: [Making Textured Surface Emit Light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140717/making-textured-surface-emit-light)) I just end up with weird shadowing.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: what does your material or scene look like? What is your current output? Needs more information or your blender file

Comment: Actually a screenshot with what you have achieved so far would be great and maybe a still frame of Ori how you want it to look as a comparison.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just a guess. I didn't get much detail at 6:10 of the video, it just says "100% self illum diffuse".

So what I just did was taking an *Emission* and a *Diffuse* shader and mixing them together somehow with a *Layer Weight* node, since Ori looks like the emission is stronger towards the edges.

The rest is playing around with the *Color Ramp* and the *Blend* value on the *Layer Weight* node to get something that works somehow. Just note that the color of the *Diffuse* shader as well as the *Color Ramp*'s right slider are not full white but light grey.

Of course you could do something similar with a *Principled BSDF* shader. If this helped, that's fine - but I'm not sure if this the look you want. (The eyes have a different material.)

[image: self illum]

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. I was definitively thinking in the right terms here, but you made it all click together. Worked exactly as i wanted it!

Comment: @starfckr Oh, nice to know that it's what you wanted. Glad I could help. By the way, your username makes me think of Nine Inch Nails.

Comment: That is correctly thought on your end. Good catch! :)