# Emission Material should not emit light (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a scene where I want to use Objects with a nice Neon glare, but without actually emitting Light. 
Is there a way in cycles to do that?

I use an Emissive Shader and put in the glare with the compositor. This is actually working fine already, but as I mentioned my scene gets lighten up by the emissive objects too. How can I change that

[image]

((In Eevee it is already working, but I want cycles))

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/58280#58280

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the emission only for the camera rays :

With camera ray filtering :

[image]

Without :

[image]